# Object.assign and ... spread operator fail silent, don't add elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

I have problems with Object.assign and ... spread operator. I need to process values (object with name and value tha are objects).

Example my values object:

```
{
  id: "12",
  name: "Hotel MESSI", 
  email: "myemail@aol.com", 
  phone: "+001060666661",
  otherfields: "{ 
     country: 'ZW',
     city: 'Zurick'
  }"
}
```

otherfields comes from graphql , so it's string, i must convert to object.
With my process I look for this result:

```
{
  id: "12",
  name: "Hotel MESSI", 
  email: "myemail@aol.com", 
  phone: "+001060666661",
  country: 'ZW',
  city: 'Zurick'
}
```

The code have more code that I paste here, there is a lot of controls for values and conversion but mainly, the idea is reassing values,

With these two case assign to the same variable is not working:

Case 1, with object.assign

```
processValues = (values)=>
  let newValues = {...values}; // 
  for (const fieldName in Tables[table].fields) {
    let value = values[fieldName];
    value = JSON.parse(value); 
    newValues = { ...newValues, ...value};                
    console.error('after mix',newValues);
```

Case 2, with object.assign

```
processValues = (values)=>
  let newValues = Object.assign({}, values}; // 
  for (const fieldName in Tables[table].fields) {
    let value = values[fieldName];
    value = JSON.parse(value); 
    newValues =  Object.assign( newValues, value};                
    console.error('after mix',newValues);
```

How it's works, when I use a new variable, by example:

```
newValues2 =  Object.assign( newValues, value};
```

but my idea is not use another variable because , i need to get values and set values for the original variable 'newValues' , if I use another variable the code would be more cumbersome.

I'm using in a project with create-react-app. I don't know if it's a problem with babel, because Object.assign and  spread operator are not inmmutable; or  yes ?

INFO:

Tables[table].fields is a object with definition por my table structure, there therea  lot of rules, but basically i need to know why object and ... does not work

Comment: where does `Tables[table].fields` come from? what are the values of it?

Comment: That `JSON.stringify` call makes no sense. You don't want JSON.

Comment: You are also missing braces in your arrow function.

Comment: sorry it's just parts of code,  full code have no error syntaxis

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, original is not stringify, it's  parse

Comment: 2 hours ago, Sagiv asked what `Tables[table].fields` is, and still no answer....

Comment: I've replied that i've updated my answer

Comment: That is not a helpful information. Please provide sample data for `Table[table]`. We cannot just guess.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `JSON.stringify` will not help, as this will produce a JSON string, which will have an entirely different behaviour when spreading it (you get the individual characters of that string).

Here is how you can achieve the result with "otherfields" as the special field (you can add other fields in the array I have used):

```js
const processValues = values =>
    Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(values).map( ([key, val]) => 
        ["otherfields"].includes(key) ? val : { [key]: val }
    ));

// Example:    
const values = {
    id: "12",
    name: "Hotel MESSI", 
    email: "myemail@aol.com", 
    phone: "+001060666661",
    otherfields: { 
        country: 'ZW',
        city: 'Zurick'
    }
};        

const result = processValues(values); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry I've changed my question original code have ' otherfields' like string, so i need to .parse ,   made mistake writing JSON.stringify i use JSON.parse in the real code,  I don't want to  use .map because my code is  very large and complex...

Comment: If `otherfields` is a string, then please give the sample value for it in your question ***as a string****. It is very unclear what you actually have as input here. Just provide the variables as they really are, with their real data type. Also I don't understand your remark about `map`. Whether your code is large is not really relevant for using `map` or something else.

Comment: thanks but , why  newValues =  Object.assign( newValues, value};    does not work, that is my question on the post. and why let newValues2 =  Object.assign( newValues, value};  works;,  I can't to reassign newValues ?

Comment: The syntax is invalid of both. You have unbalanced braces and parentheses. Also fix the missing braces in your arrow functions. I can look into it if you fix those things first *in the question*. Please also provide a piece of code for the second case with `newValues2`: what is your `console.log` like then, and what does it output? Be precise in what you mean: "doesn't work" is not helpful. What is the output, how is it different from expectation, ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to assign is the target. So it's going to get changed. You can simply pass an empty object for your target if you don't want any of the sources to change.
When you are using first argument as {} then no value will change.
For more please refer it.
https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/